# Инструкция mov ассемблер. Как работает?

Tags: ассемблер

Верны ли следующие операции? Если нет, то почему?

1. `mov 726D, [7E5D]`
2. `mov [726D], BX`
3. `mov [DX], [CD5D]`
4. `mov [BX], [DX]`
5. `mov [DX], AX`

И еще несколько вопросов:

1. если приемник - регистр в квадратных скобках, то это ошибка?
2. может ли вообще приемник находиться в квадратных скобках?
3. число в квадратных скобках - это ячейка памяти со смещением?

Comment: Вопрос бессмыслен. "Верны" или "не верны" операции могут быть только в конкретном ассемблере для конкретной платформы. Где в вопросе эта информация? Даже для конкретной платформы у ассемблеров есть несколько разных синтаксисов, в т.ч. с противоположным порядком операндов в командах. Где в вопросе информация о том, какой синтаксис использован?

Comment: @AnT, в вопросе достаточно информации. Невооруженным взглядом видно, что это x86, вариант синтаксиса Intel. За исключением формата чисел, примеры актуальны для любого ассемблера x86, понимающего синтаксис Intel.

Comment: @insolor Нет, в вопросе отсутствует эта информация. Даже если методом исключения эта информация "дедуцируется" однозначно, заниматься такой дедукцией мы не должны. Напоминаю, что основным критерием качества и приемлемости вопроса на SO является возможность поиска полезность данного вопроса для будущих читателей. Данный вопрос без четкого и явного указания платформы этим критериям грубейшим образом не соответствует.

Comment: @AnT, вы в каждом вопросе по Си/С++ уточняете конкретный компилятор и стандарт языка? В данном случае конкретный ассемблер не важен. По поводу поиска - 99% процентов по ассемблеру задаются по x86, с поисковыми запросами то же самое. Когда вопрос касается другой архитектуры, тогда в вопросе нужно обязательно конкретизировать.

Comment: @insolor: В вопросах по С и С++ как раз таки не нужно уточнять компилятор (если вопрос не по конкретному компилятору) и не нужно уточнять стандарт языка (если вопрос по текущему). В этом как раз и заключается фундаментальное отличие стандартизованных ЯВУ от ассемблеров.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Верность операций

1. Операция `mov 726D, [7E5D]` **неверна** потому, что в качестве приёмника инструкция `mov` принимает или регистр, или ячейку в памяти, а не число/адрес.
2. `mov [726D], BX` **верна**, потому что Вы переносите в 16-битную ячейку памяти по адресу `726D` значение 16-битного регистра `BX`.
3. `mov [DX], [CD5D]` **неверна**. Инструкция `mov` неспособна перенести значение из одной ячейки памяти в другую. Для этого существует отдельная инструкция - `movs`. Спасибо @insolor за замечание: данная инструкция переносит значение из ячейки памяти по адресу `DS:SI` в ячейку памяти по адресу `ES:DI`.
4. `mov [BX], [DX]` **неверна** по той же причине, что и предыдущая. Используйте `movs`.
5. `mov [DX], AX` **верна**. Здесь Вы переносите в 16-битную ячейку память по адресу, записанному в регистре `DX` значение 16-битного регистра `AX`.

### Вопросы

- Если `приёмник` - регистр в квадратных скобках, то это не ошибка. Это означает, что значение `источника` будет записано в ячейку памяти, находящуюся под адресом, равным значению `приёмника`.
  Таким образом, инструкция `mov [DX], AX` означает: "Запиши в ячейку под адресом `DX` значение регистра `AX`". Более того, в квадратных скобках можно производить простые математические операции: `mov [DX+8], AX` корректно.
- Да, приёмник тоже может находиться в квадратных скобках.
- Да.

Comment: `movs [DX], [CD5D]` не будет работать. `movs` работает только с адресами в регистрах `si`, `di`.

Comment: @insolor, спасибо.

Comment: @user263096,  Благодарю за объяснение. Тогда такой вопрос. Преподаватель в объяснял, что ответом для команды вида mov bx, [75A2] будет "пересылка в регистр bx содержимого ячейки 75А2 со сдвигом на 1, т.е. в bx будет записано содержимое ячейки 75А3". Это верно? Т.е. мы записываем содержимое ячейки с таким адресом,а не само это число?

Comment: @An.Skvrts, не будет никакого сдвига, в регистр будет записано 2 байта (потому что 2-байтовый регистр) начиная со смещения 75A2.

Answer (score 3):

- 1 - в число нельзя ничего записать (только в регистр или в ячейку памяти)
- 2 - корректно
- 3, 4 - с помощью `mov` нельзя записать напрямую из памяти в память.
- 5 - корректно

---

1. Не ошибка. Команда вида `mov [ax], 726Dh` - число будет записано по адресу, лежащему в регистре `ax`.
2. Да. Это легко проверить, если попробовать скомпилировать такую команду.
3. В 16-битном (реальном) режиме адресации - это смещение относительно сегментного регистра (для получения фактического адреса нужно знать еще значение сегментного регистра), в защищенном режиме - это виртуальный адрес.